# Find the minimum vector in a set of vectors.

Tags: vectors, computer-science

Suppose $V$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $|V|=n$ i.e.
$$
V=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}.
$$
Now suppose $v_{i} \in V$ is a vector such that for all vectors $v_j \in V$ with $j \neq i$, we have:

$$
v_i[k] \le v_j[k],
$$

where $v_i[k]$ and $v_j[k]$ denote the $k$-th component of $v_i$ and $v_j$, respectively.

Now the question I want to ask is this: is there any algorithm to find such a vector (if it exists)? If so, what is its time complexity?

Comment: I'm a little confused. It's not necessarily guaranteed that such a $v_i$ exists, right? For example, $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1)$?

Comment: @paulinho Thanks for pointing this out let me change the question to exclude such example cases.

Comment: Not that it matters, but your title says minimum while the body seems to say maximum.

Comment: @angryavian Someone's edit changed it to $\ge$ instead of $\le$

Comment: It's a finite problem, so of course there's an algorithm. Just look at each component of each vector in turn, and do the comparisons. Whether there is a more efficient algorithm, I don't know.

Comment: @Gerry I wish that were a feasible solution i am already aware that we can check it for each vector but that is the reason i mentioned time complexity here. i wish there is an efficient solution..

Comment: If you know such a vector exists, then wouldn't it necessarily be $(\min_i v_i[1], \min_i v_i[2], \ldots, \min_i v[d])$?

Comment: @AdnanAhmed Taking the component-wise minimum of the vectors takes $O(nd)$ time.